# Counting runs in columns of a matrix

Tags: matlab, run-length-encoding

I have a matrix of `1s` and `-1s` with randomly interspersed `0s`:

```
%// create matrix of 1s and -1s

hypwayt = randn(10,5);
hypwayt(hypwayt > 0) =  1;
hypwayt(hypwayt < 0) = -1;

%// create numz random indices at which to insert 0s (pairs of indices may  
%// repeat, so final number of inserted zeros may be < numz)

numz = 15;
a = 1;
b = 10;
r = round((b-a).*rand(numz,1) + a);
s = round((5-1).*rand(numz,1) + a);

for nx = 1:numz
    hypwayt(r(nx),s(nx)) = 0
end
```

**Input:**

```
hypwayt =

-1     1     1     1     1
 1    -1     1     1     1
 1    -1     1     0     0
-1     1     0    -1     1
 1    -1     0     0     0
-1     1    -1    -1    -1
 1     1     0     1    -1
 0     1    -1     1    -1
-1     0     1     1     0
 1    -1     0    -1    -1
```

I want to count how many times the `nonzero` elements are repeated in a column, to produce something like this:

> The basic idea is (provided by @rayryeng) For each column independently, every time you hit a unique number, you start incrementing a cumulative running counter and it increments every time you hit the same number as the previous one. As soon as you hit a new number, it gets reset to 1, except for the case when you hit a 0, and so that's 0

**Expected Output:**

```
hypwayt_runs =

 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     2     2     2
 2     2     3     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     2     0     1     2
 0     3     1     2     3
 1     0     1     3     0
 1     1     0     1     1
```

What's the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide further explanation on how `hypwayt_runs` is computed?  I don't see a pattern (unfortunately).

Comment: After staring at it for 30 minutes, I get it now.  For each column independently, every time you hit a unique number, you start incrementing a cumulative running counter and it increments every time you hit the same number as the previous one.  As soon as you hit a new number, it gets reset to 1... except for the case when you hit a 0, and so that's 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be better way I suppose, but this should work

Using [`cumsum`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html),[`diff`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html),[`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) & [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
%// doing the 'diff' along default dim to get the adjacent equality
out = [ones(1,size(A,2));diff(A)];

%// Putting all other elements other than zero to 1 
out(find(out)) = 1;

%// getting all the indexes of 0 elements
ind = find(out == 0);

%// doing 'diff' on indices to find adjacent indices
out1 = [0;diff(ind)];

%// Putting all those elements which are 1 to zero and rest to 1
out1 = 0.*(out1 == 1) + out1 ~= 1;

%// counting each unique group's number of elements
out1 = accumarray(cumsum(out1),1);

%// Creating a mask for next operation
mask = bsxfun(@le, (1:max(out1)).',out1.');

%// Doing colon operation from 2 to maxsize
out1 = bsxfun(@times,mask,(2:size(mask,1)+1).');    %'

%// Assign the values from the out1 to corresponding indices of out
out(ind) = out1(mask);

%// finally replace all elements of A which were zero to zero
out(A==0) = 0
```

**Results:**

**Input:**

```
>> A

A =

-1     1     1     1     1
 1    -1     1     1     1
 1    -1     1     0     0
-1     1     0    -1     1
 1    -1     0     0     0
-1     1    -1    -1    -1
 1     1     0     1    -1
 0     1    -1     1    -1
-1     0     1     1     0
 1    -1     0    -1    -1
```

**Output:**

```
>> out

out =

 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     2     2     2
 2     2     3     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     2     0     1     2
 0     3     1     2     3
 1     0     1     3     0
 1     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do this elegantly. +1

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks. I thought my method is long and there should be a better way to do this elegantly with little code :)

Comment: @rayryeng - when did "elegantly" become a synonym for "without using loops"? Seems like this problem can be solved easily with a nested loop and a few `if` statements (which increment, reset, or counter). Since the OP didn't mention that performance is an issue - I would argue that a loop-based solution is potentially much more readable... It's basically putting your 2nd comment to the question into code. In all fairness - I didn't try to solve the problem, and it may be more difficult than what I described...

Comment: @Dev-iL - I wrote an answer with loops, but I would argue that it **isn't elegant**. If you want to have a go at solving the problem with loops, be my guest, but when I tried it with loops, I didn't like the way I wrote it.  With that, have fun!  BTW, if you want, I can post what I did, but it's probably some of the ugliest code I've ever written. lol

Comment: @Dev-iL - I posted an answer with loops.  Even though it's readable, I don't like the solution.  You have to iterate through each element individually.

Answer (score 3):

As motivation made by Dev-IL, here's a solution using loops.  Even though that the code is readable, I would argue that it's slow as you have to iterate through each element individually.

```
hypwayt = [-1     1     1     1     1;
 1    -1     1     1     1;
 1    -1     1     0     0;
-1     1     0    -1     1;
 1    -1     0     0     0;
-1     1    -1    -1    -1;
 1     1     0     1    -1;
 0     1    -1     1    -1;
-1     0     1     1     0;
 1    -1     0    -1    -1];

%// Initialize output array
out = ones(size(hypwayt));

%// For each column
for idx = 1 : size(hypwayt, 2)
    %// Previous value initialized as the first row
    prev = hypwayt(1,idx);
    %// For each row after this point...
    for idx2 = 2 : size(hypwayt,1)        
        % // If the current value isn't equal to the previous value...
        if hypwayt(idx2,idx) ~= prev
            %// Set the new previous value
            prev = hypwayt(idx2,idx);
            %// Case for 0
            if hypwayt(idx2,idx) == 0
                out(idx2,idx) = 0;            
            end
         %// Else, reset the value to 1 
         %// Already done by initialization

        %// If equal, increment
        %// Must also check for 0
        else
            if hypwayt(idx2,idx) ~= 0
               out(idx2,idx) = out(idx2-1,idx) + 1;
            else
               out(idx2,idx) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

---

## Output

```
>> out

out =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     2     2     2
     2     2     3     0     0
     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     0     1     2
     0     3     1     2     3
     1     0     1     3     0
     1     1     0     1     1
```

Comment: Your code is much readable, clean, understandable (Elegant) than the vectorised code by mine. TBH, its even ~15x times faster than my solution. My guess is that, even though this one does element-wise, there is no overhead in each iteration as you haven't used any in-built functions inside your loop. Loops are not slow, the overhead with functions inside the loop makes it slower when we perform them element-wise. You avoided that. +1 from me :)

Comment: Nice work btw, but 2 for-loops, what a pity ... I must apologize for the 1st line of my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Building upon [rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719850/3372061), below's my take on a loop-based solution.

Inputs:

```
hypwayt = [
    -1     1     1     1     1
     1    -1     1     1     1
     1    -1     1     0     0
    -1     1     0    -1     1
     1    -1     0     0     0
    -1     1    -1    -1    -1
     1     1     0     1    -1
     0     1    -1     1    -1
    -1     0     1     1     0
     1    -1     0    -1    -1 ];

expected_out = [
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     2     2     2
     2     2     3     0     0
     1     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     2     0     1     2
     0     3     1     2     3
     1     0     1     3     0
     1     1     0     1     1 ];
```

Actual code:

```
CNT_INIT = 2;             %// a constant representing an initialized counter
out = hypwayt;            %// "preallocation"
out(2:end,:) = diff(out); %// ...we'll deal with the top row later
hyp_nnz = hypwayt~=0;     %// nonzero mask for later brevity
cnt = CNT_INIT;           %// first initialization of the counter

for ind1 = 2:numel(out)
    switch abs(out(ind1))
        case 2 %// switch from -1 to 1 and vice versa:
            out(ind1) = 1;
            cnt = CNT_INIT;
        case 0 %// means we have the same number again:
            out(ind1) = cnt*hyp_nnz(ind1); %//put cnt unless we're zero
            cnt = cnt+1;
        case 1 %// means we transitioned to/from zero:
            out(ind1) = hyp_nnz(ind1); %// was it a nonzero element?
            cnt = CNT_INIT;            
    end
end

%// Finally, take care of the top row:
out(1,:) = hyp_nnz(1,:);
```

Correctness test:

```
assert(isequal(out,expected_out))
```

I guess it may be simplified further by using some "complex" MATLAB functions, but IMHO it does seem elegant enough :)

Note: the top row of `out` is computed twice (once in the loop and once at the end), so there is a tiny inefficiency associated with computing values twice. However, it allows to put the entire logic into a single loop operating on `numel()`, which in my opinion justifies this tiny bit of extra computations.

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice problem, and since [@rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30719850/1507014) has not proposed a vectorized solution, here is mine in a few lines -- ok, it's not fair, it took me half a day to end up with this one. The basic idea is to use `cumsum` as the final function.

```
p = size(hypwayt,2);  % keep nb of columns in mind
% H1 is the mask of consecutive identical values, but kept as an array of double (it will be incremented later)
H1 = [zeros(1,p);diff(hypwayt)==0];

% H2 is the mask of elements where a consecutive sequence of identical values ends. Note the first line of trues.
H2 = [true(1,p);diff(~H1)>0];

% 1st trick: compute the vectorized cumsum of H1
H3 = cumsum(H1(:));

% 2nd trick: take the diff of H3(H2).
% it results in a vector of the lengths of consecutive sequences of identical values, interleaved with some zeros.
% substract it to H1 at the same locations
H1(H2) = H1(H2)-[0;diff(H3(H2))];

% H1 is ready to be cumsummed! Add one to the array, all lengths are decreased by one.
Output = cumsum(H1)+1;

% last force input zeros to be zero
Output(hypwayt==0) = 0;
```

And the expected output:

```
Output =

      1     1     1     1     1
      1     1     2     2     2
      2     2     3     0     0
      1     1     0     1     1
      1     1     0     0     0
      1     1     1     1     1
      1     2     0     1     2
      0     3     1     2     3
      1     0     1     3     0
      1     1     0     1     1
```

Let me add some explanations. The big trick is of course the second one, it took me a while to figure out how to compute the lengths of consecutive identical values fast. The first one is just a little trick to compute the whole thing without any for-loop. If you cumsum `H1` directly, you get the result with some offsets. These offsets are removed in a cumsum-compliant manner, by taking the local difference of some key values and removing them just after the ends of these sequences. These special values are out-numbered, I take also the first row (first line of `H2`): each first column element is seen as different from the last element of the previous column.

I hope it's a bit more clear now (and there is no flaw with some special case ...).